# Android Facebook like button always canceled

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-like, facebook-sdk-4.0

I have implemented the Facebook Like button

It's working well on several devices, but on a MotorolaX, it's not working.

When i click on the like button, i have this screen for 1 or 2 seconds

[image]

And after that i come back on my activity.

I have checked the onActivityResult and i have the result code RESULT_CANCELED

Answer (score 0):

Could you please login & logout of the facebook app installed on the device & try again?